# Limited results when using Excel BigQuery connector

Tags: excel, google-bigquery

I've pulled a data extract from BigQuery using the Excel connector but my results have been limited to 230,000 records.

Is this a limitation of the connector or something I have not done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery does have a maximum response size of 64MB (compressed).  So, depending on the size of your rows, it's quite possible that 230,000 is the maximum size response BigQuery can return.

See more info on quotas here:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy

What's the use case -- and how many rows are you expecting to be returned?  Generally BigQuery is used for large aggregate analysis, rather than results which return tons of unaggregated results.  You can dump the entire table as a CSV into Google Cloud Storage if you're looking for your raw dataset too.

Also, you may want to try running the query in the UI at:
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I assume I have passed the 64MB response size. I was trying to pull a subset of the data out to perform some low level validation on one of my data sets.

Comment: Suggest using the HASH function along with LIMIT to pull a random subset.